# How to put multiple labels in the same row as listbox in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have multiple labels with a 16x16 image in each of them. I want to put each image next to the appropriate listbox selection, but since I'm having to place each label one row below the other only one shows up next to the LB and the others below the listbox.

Some relevant code in case its helpful to illustrate:

```
def draw_icons():
    t = 0.5

    for ic in range(0, len(icons), 2):
        if (ic != len(icons) + 1):
            icons[ic].config(image=icons[ic + 1])
            icons[ic].grid(column=0, row=ic, ipadx=16, ipady=16)
            print(ic)

def place_things():
    Lb.grid(column=1, row=2, ipady=36, rowspan=1)
    Lb.config(font=lb_font, selectmode=MULTIPLE, height=len(process_list))
    Lb2.grid(column=2, row=2, ipady=36, rowspan=1)
    Lb2.config(font=lb_font, selectmode=MULTIPLE, height=len(process_list))
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: You can put those *icons* in a frame and put the frame at the same row of those listboxes.  However the alignment of those icons and the text inside listbox may not be synchronized.  Suggest to use `ttk.Treeview` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into that